# Open new window (Child-Window), and refresh parent window...........with TIME DELAY

Tags: javascript, php, parent-child, page-refresh, timedelay

I have a script which opens a new (child) window, while refreshing the parent page.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     function OpenWindow() {
        window.open ('start_process.php', 'newwindow', config='height=670,   
  width=1400, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no,   
  location=no, directories=no, status=no');  
        window.location = 'www.example.com';
         }
    </script>
```

However, this process is rather "blitz" --- it happens in the blink of an eye :)

I would like to add a time-delay to the second part of the process : the refreshing of the parent-page.

Meaning, once the child-window is opened, I would like a few seconds of delay BEFORE the parent-page is refreshed.

(Not sure if this is even possible, because I cannot find anything remotely similar online)

I know there are several timer-functions and scripts available. But, can I add a timer to this particular situation?

I tried doing this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function OpenWindow() {
        window.open ('start_process.php', 'newwindow', config='height=670,  
 width=1400, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no,   
 location=no, directories=no, status=no');  
        window.location = ('www.example.com',2000);
         }
    </script>
```

But, it did not work;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  window.location = 'www.example.com';
}, 2000);
```

This will redirect the browser to `www.example.com` after 2 seconds.